# ShareKit 2.0: Cancel Facebook share/FBSession

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I'm using Sharekit 2.0 using a button to share a text on facebook;

```
SHKItem *post = [SHKItem text: @"my text"];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:post];
```

However, executing the code, if user is not logged in on fb, the fb log in window is brought to the front (fb app or safari) and a FBSession is created (My app is in the background). What is the correct way to handle users that do not wish to log in, that is "cancelling" the share (and remove the "Loggin in" activity indicator that is shown)? Is there something missing in my setup?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the Sharekit wiki properly, [SHKFacebook handleDidBecomeActive]; did the trick in my case..